# python Определить среднее значение пиков

Tags: python, массивы

Имеется массив данных такого вида [image: массив данных с пиками]

Необходимо найти средний вид всех пиков, т.е. определить пики в массиве данных, записать каждый пик в отдельный список, а затем вычислить среднее значение каждой соотвествующей точки всех пиков.

```
i=7800
peak=[]

 while i<8249:
    i=i+1
    if massiv[i]>0.02:
            peak.append(float(massiv[i]))
```

Пока только выбрал из изначального массива все элементы больше определенного числа (для начала 0.02)

затем по таблице с данными посмотрел границы пиков и записал четыре из них. после чего вычислил среднее значение соотвествующих точек. однако пики имеют разную ширину, поэтому взял только первые 7 точек по минимальной ширине пика

```
peak1=peak[0:12]
peak2=peak[13:22]
peak3=peak[23:31]
peak4=peak[32:42]

i=-1
peakmid=[]
while i<7:
    i=i+1
    peakmid.append((peak1[i]+peak2[i]+peak3[i]+peak4[i])/4)


plt.plot(peakmid)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот примерно что должно получится.

Comment: А вы сами пробовали что-нибудь сделать? И уточните что такое средний вид всех пиков? Может вам нужно найти среднее значение амплитуды пиков?

Comment: Вам нужно найти все экстремумы одномерного массива?

Comment: @Avernial пробовал вручную это сделать, но таких графиков предполагается довольно много, поэтому ищу программное решение.Под средним видом имеется в виду среднее значение амплитуды и ширины основания

Comment: Я имел ввиду что программно пытались сделать?

Comment: @Avernial добавил то, что уже проделал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мысль примерно такая: есть порог (пусть будет 0.02), как только значение в массиве превышает этот порог - считаем это началом пика, запоминаем его индекс. Дальше, пока значение превышает порог - пик продолжается. Как только перестает превышать - считаем концом пика, делаем срез значений массива от начала до конца пика, добавляем в список пиков (ну или делаем функцию-генератор и возвращаем через `yield`).

Выглядеть будет примерно так:

```
def get_peaks(arr, thres):  # Параметры: массив, пороговое значение
   peak_start = -1  # -1 будет обозначать, что пик еще не начался или уже закончился
   for i, value in enumerate(arr):
       if peak_start >= 0:
           if value < thres:
               # Возвращаем срез массива с данным пиком:
               yield arr[peak_start:i]  
               peak_start = -1  # Отмечаем, что пик закончился
       else:
           if value >= thres:
               peak_start = i

   # Не забываем про пики, которые могут граничить с концом массива:
   if peak_start >= 0:
       yield arr[peak_start:]

# Пример вызова:
print(list(get_peaks(massiv, 0.02)))
```

Далее, у нас есть список пиков. Нужно пройти по всем пикам параллельно, взяв среднее от каждого значения в соответствующей точке. Для более коротких пиков заполняем 0 до нужной длины (параметр `fillvalue` в функции `zip_longest`).

```
peaks = get_peaks(massiv, 0.02)

from itertools import zip_longest
mean_profile = [sum(row)/len(row) for row in zip_longest(*peaks, fillvalue=0)]
```

Comment: Искренне благодарю! Однако вот со вторым действием вышла загвоздка.     `mean_profile` в исходном виде не сработал. пришлось заменить `zip_longest` на `izip_longest`. Однако не в этом сама суть вопроса. Питон ругается на то, что `get_peaks` должен быть итерируемым. Заменил его на `peaks`. Больше не ругается, однако выводит тот же самый `peaks` без изменений

Comment: `zip_longest` - это для Python 3, для Python 2 - `izip_longest`. Код исправил (заменил `get_peaks` на `peaks` и добавил звездочку), проверьте теперь.

Comment: Да, всё заработало теперь!